# paste single line command in R console without executing

Tags: r

Since I have started using R I have noticed inconsistent behaviours when pasting a complete single command line in the R GUI console. Sometimes the command is executed, sometime is not. I tried to use the "paste commands only" but the command is still executed and the option does not seem to have any effect. I want to past a complete command and not execute it.

How do I control what happens when I paste a single line?

EDIT: i think the issue is that I am also copying from notepad the "enter" character, so that's what make the command run right away. Is there a way to avoid this?

Comment: Please share a reproducible example, and clarify your "without any luck" statement. What are you inputting? What is the expected output?

Comment: Are you able to paste the same clipboard content into Notepad or other application?   Does it make a difference if you use (1) ctrl-v, (2) edit | paste, (3) the paste icon along the top, (4) file | edit and then paste into the R editor and then while the cursor is on the desired line press ctrl-r or (5) issue source("clipboard")?  What version of R are you using?

Comment: @G.Grothendieck i have 3.2.2 and I can paste no problem in any other application, using ctrl-v or the context menu produce or the file menu the same result (running the command), past commands only does not work. I am using notepad.

Comment: @G.Grothendieck actually you made me think about something, i think the issue is that I am also copying from notepad the "enter" character, so that's what make the command run right away. Is there a way to avoid this?

Comment: I think Josh's answer discusses this but, yes, you can copy the newline or not from Notepad. If Notepad has only one line in it and no following blank line then it's likely there is No newline in Notepad so ctrl-a ctrl-c in Notepad followed by ctrl-v in R will not have the newline and so not execute until you manually press newline in R.  If there is one line in Notepad plus a second blank line then ctrl-a ctrl-c will get the newline that caused the blank line to show up and it will execute when pasting into R.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you do not copy a newline character at the end of the command, it will not be executed when you paste it. You will need to enter one manually.

Rather than copy/paste, you might want to use an editor where you can highlight the code you want to run and then send it to the R console via a button or shortcut key. The Windows R GUI has this feature, as does Rstudio.